# Permission Denied on Yum Installation

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, yum, root, privileges

i am trying to install yum on my Ubuntu Server 20.04, i am using an administrator user which has a root privileges (since i have added such administrator user to the root line in `visudo`).
So i downloaded the Yum package and copied it to the administrator desktop, i am trying to use the `./yummain.py update`, but it says permission denied.
Why is this happening although the administrator has a root privileges?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is yummain.py? Also, you being in the sudoers file still means you need to use `sudo` to gain root privileges.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this is to install the yum package, yummain.py is a folder found in the zip folder of the yum package i downloaded, i tried using sudo (sudo ./yummain.py update), but it says no command found for ./yummain.py, but when i use ./yummain.py while i am logged in with the administrator user it says permission denied

Comment: if yummain.py is a folder (that seems unlikely, considering the name), then you can't execute it – it's a folder. this all makes no sense. It also sounds a lot as if you're doing something you really shouldn't be doing, and which you attribute a purpose that doesn't exist...

Comment: Is there a package that's in yum that's not in Ubuntu? In my experience, most companies/projects releases an rpm and deb package.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even want to install software with `yum` on an Ubuntu system?  That would be a good way to break your own system.

If you want to install some .rpm packages on your ubuntu system then:

1. Check to see if there's an Ubuntu .deb package for the same program, and install that instead.
2. Check to see if there's an alternative program packaged for Ubuntu that does roughly the same thing, and install that instead.
3. Check to see if you really need the software that you want to install. If you don't, then don't install it.
4. If there's no package and you really need the software, then compile and build your own .deb package
5. As a last resort, if there's no .deb package, use [alien](http://kitenet.net/%7Ejoey/code/alien/) to convert the .rpm to .deb and install it with `dpkg`.

Note that "figure out some way to force-install yum and break my system by installing .rpm packages" is not listed above.  That's because it's a terrible idea and will break your system.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, but i don't want to install .rpm packages using yum, i want to install something called mlocate using yum package, i have searched a lot and found that i can install such mlocate package using yum. is there another way to install mlocate, i am using mlocate, since i am backing up such VM using Veeam backup, the backupjob is giving a warning that mlocate is not found (since mlocate is related for indexing files), is there anyway i can install mlocate without using yum, because i have not seen other than yum in my searches, Thanks!

Comment: [mlocate](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mlocate&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) has been in ubuntu for years (since at least 18.04 and probably long before), you should just be able to install it with `sudo apt install mlocate`.   If you're using ubuntu, your first and best option when you want to install something is to search the Ubuntu package repository - e.g. with `apt-cache search mlocate`.   That was my first point above "check to see if there's an ubuntu package".

Comment: BTW, you should run `apt update` once before either of those commands to make sure your system has the most up-to-date package lists.

Comment: Thanks!, yes this was solved by just  using the sudo apt install mlocate, Searches on google gave me to use yum to install the mlocate, but didn't it was already found in the ubuntu repository, Thanks, please edit your answer, so that i can mark it as a solution, Thanks again!

Comment: @Ahmad I'm happy with my answer as is because your question was not asking how to install mlocate, it was about installing yum on ubuntu in order to install something.   My answer speaks directly to that.